# How can I increase the timeout in Download Manager?

Tags: java, android, zip

I have a functionality in my file/directory browsing app where the user can download the current directory they are in. This works for a folder with a moderate size *(<100 MB)* so zipping doesn't take much time on the server side, but then when the size of the folder is quite large *100 MB+*, it takes time to zip

And that's where the Download Manager screws up. It restarts the download quite a number of times before notifying about the zip download being unsuccessful. Is there a way to increase the timeout of downloading a file in Download Manager?

**Note that we're also trying to improve the zipping process *(currently a simple ZipArchive implementation in php)* by live streaming on the go in the server side implementation, but we're also looking for other options.**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to increase the timeout of downloading a file in Download Manager?

No, sorry, short of building your own custom ROM or own Android hardware.

You could replace `DownloadManager` with your own downloading code, using your favorite HTTP client API (e.g., OkHttp), in which case you would have greater control over things like timeouts.